# Got an email from an employee of a company with a remote job offer. How do I know if it's genuine?

Tags: job-offer, developer

I got an email from an HR and a Project Manager about a job vacancy for Fullstack Software development job from a Russian based company. It is a remote job, not a relocation job.
The email contained a brief description about the job,about the company, link to book an interview slot and a social messenger contact number.

To check I did visit their official website and found that job vacancy.
I did send an e-mail to their support team asking if these members are their employees, but didn't get any response from them.

So for time being, I thought to give a round of interview:

- 1st I filled the details and selecting date-time in the interview slot app (link that was shared in the email), I received a google calender mail with the online meeting link.
- Then a video call about personal introduction with the *Product manager* (who had sent a mail about the job vacancy).
- 3rd was a mail from the *BR* asking to enter name, email, salary expectation and followed by link to the tests (each test for each programming language - JS and Python).
- After clearing the tests, the next day they are asking my contact number having social messenger for discussing about the offer.

How do I know if this is legitimate?

Comment: Hello Sarath welcome to The Workplace. Question: What makes you think it's not legit? Please share with us more details to understand why this makes you doubt about its legitimacy, and also explain what is the problem you want us to help with. While you are at it, please check [help/dont-ask] to see which/how things are off-topic to ask here. Cheers

Comment: Do you feel that this is "to good to be true"? Please enhance. Also, do you have other jobs lined up? Other options to consider? How come you received that email do you know any of the senders? If you don't.... then I get it why you may think this is fishy... again, please clarify

Comment: Did the email come from the right domain for the company? When you replied, did it go to that email (i.e. not a "reply-to" to a different domain)? When you replied to that email did they then respond? Did you look up the people on LinkedIn?

Comment: Hi @DJClayworth. Around 2 weeks back, I did send a mail to the company's support team requesting to confirm if these members are their company employees. However, I didn't receive any response from them till now.

Comment: @Sarath That's not what I asked. I asked if the original emails come from the company domain, and if responses to them are received and responded to?

Comment: Hi @DarkCygnus. No, I don't know any of the senders. As a matter of fact, I didn't know about this company until the moment I got this email (of course, there are many famous companies in many parts of the world that I still don't know)

Comment: Did the emails come from the domain of the company?

Comment: Yes @DJClayworth, the email-IDs were matching to that of the domain name.

Comment: And did you reply to them? And did the replies go to the matching domain? And did they get replied to? If so it's very likely the emails really did come from the company.

Comment: Sorry @DJClayworth but no, didn't reply back to that email. They had provided a link to book a date (a calendar app) for meeting and meeting link to join the call on that date. After the date and time was selected, I got an email in the form of a Google Calendar invitation.

Comment: @Sarath, You are not located in Russia? Is that why you're asking? What do you mean by legitimate? The company could be fake. The company web site could be fake. The company could be real, but decide not to pay you for your work. There could be a thousand reasons why a job offer is not legitimate. But tell us, why do you think this job offer could be fake? What is your gut feeling telling you?

Comment: Hi @StephanBranczyk! No, I am not located in Russia. I heard that one of my friend's friend who got an offer from a company in Canada. They also had one or two rounds of interview and video calls with him and gave him job offer. Later, he realised is was hoax and cancelled his resignation in the current company as he was on notice period. Also, this is a remote job not a relocation job. Never had an interview for a remote job, so kind of nervous and being cautious

Comment: @Sarath, You're a developer? Right? Inspect the full headers of the email you've received. Do a domain lookup and look at their whois information. Send back a thank you email to their email addresses the next chance you get. Is this for a remote job? If they expect you to relocate, call the Russian consulate/embassy and ask them about the paperwork needed to get a work visa in Russia. This is only a partial answer, but it should help you get started at least.

Comment: @Sarath Please edit the answers to all these comments into the question.

Comment: How are you supposed to get your contact details to them?

Comment: If you didn't apply for a position and they coldcalled you, I would just assume it's a scam.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the company is legit, then do some research outside of the resources provided by the company itself.

Did anyone else write something about the company? Any mentions of them in media? Any testimonies about their services or products or perhaps even from past employees? Any other companies claiming to do business with them? What about the people mentioned on the company website? Does anything show up if you google these people? Does the company website list any company identification numbers you can look up in any publicly accessible databases?

But if you don't find anything, then that's not certain proof that they are a fantasy company. They could simply be a new startup.

Comment: In certain countries, you could also check to see if the company exists by verifying it is registered. Maybe it's similar in Russia? (Mind you, this would probably require knowledge of the Russian language and Russian bureaucracy.)

Comment: @zmike That's what I meant with the last sentence of the second paragraph.